# method of super-class called WHEN super has a str attr + instance of sub is created in a loop + instance is stored in a vector as a pointers of super

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I can't reach a method of a sub-class' instance when several conditions are merged :

- There is in the super-class an attribute of type string.
- The instance have been created in a loop
- The instance is stored in a vector that takes super-class pointers

It's so look like this :

```
class Parent
{
  public :
    string name;
    virtual void myMethod() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
  public :
    void myMethod();
};

void Child::myMethod()
{
  cout << "I'm a child";
}

int main(void)
{
  vector<Parent*> children;

  for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 1; i++ )
  {
    Child c;

    children.push_back(&c);
  }

  (*children[0]).myMethod();
}
```

In that case the code over with an error : "pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception". I guess that it's trying to access to 'Parent::myMethod' that is virtual and so fail. To avoid that issue I can :
- Remove the attribute 'name' of the super-class
- Change the type of that attribute (to int for exemple)
- Append the elements to the vector from outside of the for loop.

I just can't figure what is going on in that specific case...

Comment: As said in an answer, the object _c_ of type _Child_ is already destructed by the time you try to access a pointer to it in your vector. How to fix? Easy. `Child *c = new Child(); children.push_back(c);` done and done. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep and who will clean up that mess ? why not smart pointers? Btw the section for answers is below :P

Comment: @Morgan I hope you don't have a virtual destructor for the sake of being an example.

Comment: @tobi303 - depends on who uses the code and why. Some prefer c++ with all the bells and whistles, while others amongst us are perfectly satiated with using the language as "c with classes". I'm typically writing things that need to be tiny and experience has shown my gcc/g++ cross-compiler for Atmel mcus doesn't serve me well when I make use of the language's more complex features.. I'd rather drink more coffee than spend more money on 10,000 chips. ;) Yeah, the answer section has always been there during my 5 year stay, thanks. :)

Comment: @enhzflep Thank's for the solution, I will try with this. I wil also look at smart pointers that I haven't explored yet (I'm using c++ since only 3 days)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one "condition" that matters here: the pointers you push in the vector point to garbage when `Child c;` goes out of scope:

```
{
  Child c;                   // this object lives only in this scope !!

  children.push_back(&c);    // <-- &c is fine here
}                            // <-- already here it is not !

(*children[0]).myMethod();   // ***BOOM***
```

Maybe you got the impression that it is a specific combination of conditions to get the error, but thats just because dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour, so sometimes it may look like it worked when actually it is never correct.

Comment: I was supposing that the problem was only linked to the loop but the fact that things works without the attribute was confusing me. Thank you for the help !