# passing/modifying a FileOutputStream

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm writing a C++ program which should continuously write to a text file inside an OnIdle event loop (BTW, I'm using wxWidgets -3.0.3 and Visual Studio 17). For this purpose, I'm creating a TextOutputStream as described in the code below inside GetData().

Here gui_magsens->GetFilePath() simply gets a file path from a wxFilePickerCtrl and ActivateDataLoop(true) triggers the OnIdle loop. Now, what I would like to have is a global reference to my *tos* so that I can use it inside the OnIdle loop without having to create it (and close it) every iteration(not efficient and leads me to unhandled exceptions). **What is the best (or cleanest) way to achieve this?** What I have found so far is that you could use a pointer to the stream (as shown below), which compiles fine, but throws me a "read access violation" exception(apparently expected as the pointer points to an already "dead" stream). Also, **is there a neat workaround without using pointers?**

```
//----main.h----//

//...bunch of variables and functions
wxFileOutputStream* pFos;
wxTextOutputStream* pTos;
```

---

```
//---main.cpp----//

void wxMagSens::GetData()
{       
//create stream
wxString f_path = gui_magsens->GetFilePath();
wxFileOutputStream fos(f_path);
wxTextOutputStream tos(fos, wxEOL_NATIVE, wxConvUTF8); 
//ptrs
pFos = &fos;
pTos = &tos;
ActivateDataLoop(true); 
} 

void wxMagSens::OnIdleDataLoop(wxIdleEvent & evt)
{           
  //write to file
  pTos->WriteDouble(some_double);//Here's the exception
  //etc...
}

int wxMagSens::OnExit()
{
//USBInterface.USBClose();
if(pFos->IsOk()){ pFos->Close();}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: make references (not pointers) your default when you dont want a copy, it will make your life easier

Comment: btw your streams live in the scope of the `GetData` functions and pointers to them will be invalid outside of `GetData`. You need to keep them alive as long as you want to use them

Comment: this is completely unrelated, but same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959875/method-of-super-class-called-when-super-has-a-str-attr-instance-of-sub-is-crea/45959986?noredirect=1#comment78880266_45959986

Comment: That is what c++ class members are designed for.

Comment: Thanks guys. That sufficed. Just wanted to know what the "right" way was. I was already trying to use a reference but was running into problems using "new Whatever()". Now it works the way I want. however it gives me some memory leaks when I close it(guess it comes from new). I checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544090/detected-memory-leaks, went to the line causing the problem and there's a comment telling that you should live with this leak as it is unlikely to happen. Are these leaks "normal"? Btw, I tried to explicitly destroy the objects but it still throws the same.